# What's the difference between # , % and $ signs in Struts tags?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, expression, ognl

I'm working with Struts 2 and when I'm accessing `ValueStack` variables I don't know whether to use `%` or `#` or `$`. I try all of them until I find the correct one.

Can **anybody explain** what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

**Use of # (pound sign)**

OGNL is used to refer to objects in the ActionContext as follows:

- `objectName`: object in the ValueStack (default/root object in the OGNL context), such as an Action property
- `#objectName`: object in the ActionContext but outside of the ValueStack, specifically...

  - `#objectName`: ActionContext object that has been created using the Struts2 data tags with the default action scope (e.g., `<s:set name="foo" value="'Testing'" />`, referenced by `<s:property value="#foo" />`)
  - `#parameters.objectName`: request parameter
  - `#request.objectName`: request-scoped attribute
  - `#session.objectName`: session-scoped attribute
  - `#application.objectName`: application-scoped attribute
  - `#attr.objectName`: attribute in page, request, session, or application scope (searched in that order)

The scoped map references above (parameters, request, session, and application) can be made one of two ways:

- `#scopeName.objectName`  or
- `#scopeName['objectName']`

**Use of % (percent sign)**

`%{ OGNL expression }` is used to force OGNL evaluation of an attribute that would normally be interpreted as a String literal.

Example: `<s:property value="myProperty" default="%{myDynamicDefaultValue}" />`

**Use of @ (at sign)**

The @ symbol is used to make references to static properties and methods. Note that you may need to enable this in your Struts2 properties: `struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess=true`

Examples:

```
@my.package.ClassName@MY_STATIC_PROPERTY
@my.package.ClassName@myStaticMethod
```

**Use of $ (dollar sign)**

Struts2 OGNL does not make special use of the dollar sign. However, it can be used to evaluate normal JSTL expressions. For example:

Struts2: `<h1><s:property value="#pageTitle" /></h1>`
    *(is equivalent to...)*
JSTL: `<h1>${pageTitle}</h1>`

Comment: About $ please note that the `<s:property>` is xss hack safe while `${}` is not. Use `${}` with care!

Comment: Exactly, [as we discussed in your Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23367430/1654265), that I'm linking because it could be useful to future readers

Comment: Do not count on `allowStaticMethodAccess` it will be removed from struts framework soon http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28018861/struts-2-refactoring-code-to-avoid-ognl-static-method-access

Answer (score 10):

The framework uses a standard naming context to evaluate OGNL expressions. The top level object dealing with OGNL is a Map (usually referred as a context map or context). OGNL has a notion of there being a root (or default) object within the context. In expression, the properties of the root object can be referenced without any special "marker" notion. References to other objects are marked with a pound sign (#).

The framework sets the OGNL context to be our ActionContext, and the value stack to be the OGNL root object. (The value stack is a set of several objects, but to OGNL it appears to be a single object.) Along with the value stack, the framework places other objects in the ActionContext, including Maps representing the application, session, and request contexts. These objects coexist in the ActionContext, alongside the value stack (our OGNL root).

```
                 |
                 |--application
                 |
                 |--session
   context map---|
                 |--value stack(root)
                 |
                 |--request
                 |
                 |--parameters
                 |
                 |--attr (searches page, request, session, then application scopes)
```

refer this for more details

[OGNL basis](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11.1/docs/ognl.html)

basically struts2 put object value Stack as top most object and OGNL is used to refer them.root object can be referenced without any special "marker" or with `%` while References to other objects are marked with a pound sign (#). # is basically used to refer object/values from Application/Session etc.

Comment: <s:iterator value="places" status="portStatus2">
     <tr>
 <td>
     <s:a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.open('%{link}');"><s:property value="name"/></s:a>
 </td>
     </tr>                
</s:iterator>

Comment: what link is here as i can't see this, but accordingly it should be the top most element in value stack or if you are using iterator and refereeing its value that means when iterator is moving through the value e=it placing each individual element on top of value stack one at a time and %{link} is refereeing that top stack value

Comment: Sorry I'm New in this Site I meant in my program i have list called places and I'm doing this!

<s:iterator value="l" status="portStatus">
 <s:if test="%{#portStatus.count == page+1}">
  <tr>
   <td rowspan="11"  width="50%" align="right">
    <img src="${imagePath}" alt="Logo" />
   </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <s:a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.open('%{link}');"><s:property value="name"/></s:a>
  </td>
 </tr>                
</s:iterator>

This is working but i dont know why i'm putting this stuff there!!
i just try them all to get answer!!

Comment: first better for you to learn about struts2 basic how request processing goes in to it what value stack is and how OGNL is working inside it, that will help you to understand better.

Comment: Thats good since in-order to understand you need to first understand how Struts2 framework is pushing the object in value stack and how we can access that

Comment: @umeshawasthi It's not so much that it "appears to be a single object", but that OGNL will traverse down the stack until it finds something that can satisfy an expression. That's actually important, because the order of which things are pushed onto the stack, and what's pushed when, can be the cause (or the solution!) to a few types of problems.

Comment: @dave:i am agree with you and i am aware about how ognl traverse in value stack but yes put wrong words in explaining.Thanks for this !!

Comment: @umeshawasthi It was for for Khashayar but I can only tag with one person :)

Comment: @dave :) but still i explained about top most object on value stack and not how OGNL resolve property value down the stack

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks Dave, at first i was just wanted to know what they do but now that i read the whole thing i exactly get whats going on! It's Always better to do something completely from the beginning !

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete the @Devon Biere ...

**Use of $ (dollar sign)**

You can use `${}` in your resource files too. The struts will automatically use OGNL to parse `${}`. For example

```
sample.foo.bar=This is some ${someProperty} //If the someProperty is in valueStack
sample.welcome.message=Welcome dear ${#session.CurrentUser.farsiFirstName}
```

Please note the `$` sign here is just a trigger which ask struts to evaluate the string against OGNL, please do not confuse it with `${}` in JSTL

[Struts 2 Dynamic message with OGNL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32411365/struts-2-dynamic-message-with-ognl)