# Struts 2 Action tags, retrieving properties

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts

If I had a typical setup with an action that forwards to the JSP I would request my properties like so:

`<s:property value="myVariable" />`

where myVariable is a variable in the action.

I want to use action tags like this in another page:

```
<s:action name="actionName" executeResult="false"> 
    <s:param name="switch">true</s:param>
</s:action>
```

How do I access `myVariable` when using an action tag like above? I tried `<s:property value="myVariable" />` but it doesn't work.

Comment: `myVariable` is a property of the `actionName` Action? And you are using `<s:property value="myVariable" />` inside the `s:action` element or outside (below) it?

Comment: Yes myVariable is a property in the class of actionName action. `<s:property value="myVariable" />` is below `s:action`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write `<s:property value="myVariable" />`, Struts looks for the property  `myVariable` in its "Value Stack". The current action is in the ValueStack, and that's why the typical setup works. Now, in the case of

```
<s:action name="actionName" executeResult="false"> 
    <s:param name="switch">true</s:param>
</s:action>
<s:property value="myVariable" />
```

when the last line is executed the `actionName` action has already executed, the current action is not that but the main ("outer") one . If you want to acces properties of your "inner" action, you have several alternatives, two of them are shown in the [docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/action.html):

Either add the `var` attribute so that the executed (inner) action is assigned to a variable and reference it with the [#  syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11620838/277304):

```
<s:action name="actionName" var="innerAction" executeResult="false">
   <s:param name="switch">true</s:param>
</s:action>
<s:property value="#innerAction.myVariable" />
```

Or, in your action method, add your property value explicitly to some scope ( eg: attribute)

```
// in your inner action: 
ServletActionContext.getRequest().setAttribute("myVariable", "blah blah");

<s:property value="#attr.myVariable" />
```

Disclaimer: I've not tested this