# How to pass output of an <s:action> to a <s:url> value parameter in a JSP view?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I haven't touched Struts2 in a couple of years and have to do some maintenance on some JSP pages.  But I can't figure out the proper syntax to pass the output from an `<s:Action>` tag to an `<s:url>` tag.

I'd like to do the following:

```
    <s:action name="loadPath" namespace="/files" flush="false" var="filePath" />
    <s:url value="#filePath.path"/>
```

But that does not work.  However, I can see that my path property is properly set by doing:

```
<s:property value="#filePath.path" />
```

I've played around with %, # and $, but can't seem to find the right combination to get the value off the stack and into the s:url tag.

**AHA!**

After some more digging around, and trial and error, I finally found the right combination:

```
<s:url value="%{ #filePath.path }"/>
```

But I do not understand why this works.  Can anyone provide an explanation why this syntax works and not just `value="#filePath.path"`?

Comment: I tried searching for an answer and stumbled upon this:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/12150105/259889

Comment: @SidCool thanks for digging up the reference, and although it is somewhat relevant, it still does resolve the issue.  As I said, I can retrieve the value using `<s:property />` tag, but for some reason, it does not seem to work in the `<s:url />` tag.  I've updated the question to be a little more clear.

Comment: Because you need to force OGNL evaluation; the default is to assume it's just a string. Consider the `"action"` attribute; normally you'd put the name of an action in there, not an expression to be evaluated--this is the same thing.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for the explanation.  I guess I was expecting it to work the same way the property tag works, but given your explanation, I presume that the property tag, but defn, does an OGNL evaluation and is not expecting a string.  If you create an answer instead of a comment, I can give you proper credit.

Comment: There's some... confusion regarding which attributes are assumed to be OGNL and which aren't. After a couple of years I've started to always use the %{} to avoid the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure about what you are trying to achieve but perhaps these documents will help you:

- [Struts2 Action Tag Example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-action-tag-example/)
- [Struts2 URL Tag Example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-url-tag-example/)