# Index.jsp page fetch database record using struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2

Using, Struts 2 + JSP

I have an index.jsp page which I'd like to display some data from database.

I would like to have my web sever automatically fetch the data from database and send the result to struts's value stack. So I can refer to them in my index.jsp page.

I am wondering how to trigger an struts action without sending a request?

I know I can use ajax to achieve this result, but I'd like to avoid making two calls to my web sever.

Comment: You shouldn't be hitting JSP pages directly anyway, instead go through an action, and kill both birds with one solar death ray.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to use

```
<s:action >
```

tag.

Here is an example

[Struts 2 Action tags, retrieving properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12149190/struts-2-action-tags-retrieving-properties)