# Meaning of ${} in javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax

I need to work on javascript lately. Unfortunately, I am a newbie.
I have come across the following code and don't understand the meaning of ${count == 0}.

```
function body_onload()
{
    if(${count == 0})
    {
        document.getElementById("dispaly").style.display="none";
    }   
    scanImageReportFrom.shopCodes.focus();
}
```

Thank you.

---

Finally I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007858/whats-the-difference-between-and-signs-in-struts-tags) that can solve my question.

Comment: where have you found such a code?

Comment: From the project I need to follow up. Those code was written by someone in my company that I don't know.

Comment: Ok. does project contains any javascript libraries?

Comment: Like this?        

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"
   src="<%=path%>/js/common.js"></script>

Comment: That `<%=path%>` confirms the idea that you are looking at the raw source code rather than the generated output.

Answer (score 8):

It's not you. :-) That's not valid JavaScript (the `{` triggers a syntax error).

It could perhaps be a token for some pre-processor that replaces it with something before the JavaScript is passed to the JavaScript engine.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: I did say "perhaps." :-)

Comment: Then I really don't understand as it runs fine without any errors...  :O

Comment: @JohnnyTse: No, it doesn't. If that text is actually passed to a normal JavaScript engine, the engine **will** throw a syntax error. Completely gratuitous example: http://jsbin.com/azosam/1 (look in the JavaScript console, where it will say `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` or similar). Some browsers are *really subtle* about reporting JavaScript errors. All due respect, you're probably just not noticing it. :-) Try Chrome, press F12 to show dev tools, and click the Console tab. Or, as I said, something is pre-processing that before it's given to the engine.

Comment: If it's being preprocessed, `view source` can be helpful in finding out what the post-processed code looks like.

Comment: I am not sure yet.  I was trying to ask the writer about this through someone. But have not got the answer yet. Will tell the situation once I get the answer...

Comment: @JohnnyTse: Okay. But again, with the code presented, there is no question, the syntax is invalid.

Comment: Could not get answer from the writer...

But seems it is really invalid syntax as I tried to delete it and the result is same.

Comment: Delete the ${} is not same.  When I load the homepage, there is error indicating that count is not indentified.  I just did not notice the error.

Answer (score 1):

Just to update this- it is also valid ES2015/ES6

[MDN docs - template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
let a = 4;
let b = 2;
console.log(`a is ${a} and b is ${b}`);
```

Comment: Which doesn't seem related to the OP's question since it's not a template literal.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript the `${}` is used to insert a variable to a string.

```js
var foo = "cheese";
console.log(`We want to eat ${foo}!`); // This needs the grave accent (`)
// Outputs "We want to eat cheese!"
console.log("We want to eat " + foo + "!"); 
// Outputs "We want to eat cheese!"
```

Sometimes the `${}` method could be faster than using quotes.

Comment: Which doesn't seem related to the OP's question since it's not a template literal.

Answer (score 0):

*I was reading [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), where in the 2nd para of [description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#description) I found this:*

Along with having normal strings, template literals can also contain other parts called placeholders, which are embedded expressions delimited by a dollar sign and curly braces: ${expression}

*And further in [Interpolation Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#string_interpolation) I found:*

Without template literals, when you want to combine output from expressions with strings, you'd concatenate them using the "+" (plus sign) (addition operator):

```
let a = 5;
let b = 10;
console.log('Fifteen is ' + (a + b) + ' and\nnot ' + (2 * a + b) + '.');
// "Fifteen is 15 and
// not 20."
```

That can be hard to read – especially when you have multiple expressions.

With template literals, you can avoid the concatenation operator — and improve the readability of your code — by using placeholders of the form "${expression}" to perform substitutions for embedded expressions:

```
let a = 5;
let b = 10;
console.log(`Fifteen is ${a + b} and
not ${2 * a + b}.`);
// "Fifteen is 15 and

// not 20."
```

*More details of using "${}" in Template Literals is given in the [documentation of the same](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)*