# How to call an action method using OGNL

Tags: struts2, ognl, struts2-interceptors

How to call an action method using OGNL?

**`helloAction.java`**

```java
public String getQuote()
{
    return "Don't think, just do";
}
```

**`success.jsp`**

```jsp
<b>quote() :</b> <s:property value="quote()"/> <br>
```

**`struts.xml`**

```xml
<action name="greet" class="com.struts2.helloAction" >
    <interceptor-ref name="firewallStack"></interceptor-ref>
    <result name="SUCCESS">/WEB-INF/resources/success.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">/WEB-INF/resources/success.jsp</result>
</action>
```

I got the ref link from [struts 2 OGNL](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-ognl-expression-language-example-1.html)

This `quote()` method is not called. I am using xwork-2.0.1.jar and ognl-2.6.11.jar.

Comment: <s:property value="quote()"/>
Should be 
<s:property value="getQuote()"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This quote() method is not called. I am using xwork-2.0.1.jar and ognl-2.6.11.jar.

You don't have that method in your action. If you create it:

```
public String quote() {
```

and use normal OGNL method call syntax:

```
<s:property value="%{quote()}" />
```

then it will be called as desired.

For details information and syntax you can read [OGNL Language Guide](https://commons.apache.org/dormant/commons-ognl/language-guide.html).

Comment: Didn't work for me. Is it the same calling `%{XXX}` and with `${XXX}`?

Comment: It is not the same. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8007858/573032) if you need to know difference.

Answer (score 4):

Your original syntax is almost correct–just leave off the parens.

```
<s:property value="%{quote}" />
```

JavaBean contentions are more general-purpose than explicit method invocation, e.g., use JSP EL:

```
${quote}
```

JavaBean conventions are be preferred when the function takes no arguments.

Comment: It wasn't me, and I in general think it should be the preferred practice in JSPs since that machinery will always be available. But the "preferred" Nazis probably want a link. You have write access to the struts documentation? You should just add a document to that effect and put the link here, that would be funny.

Comment: @Quaternion I once had someone chide me for providing an opinion that wasn't in a book, so I put it in my book so I could quote myself. I gotta finish that other book(s) so I can quote me more ;)

Comment: @RomanC No, the question is how to call a *specific* action method, which doesn't need to use method-call syntax, because it's a getter.

Comment: @DaveNewton You should better read the question, _How to call an action method_, then _This quote() method is not called_. Do you understand which method it should call? If it uses a property name to invoke a getter on some bean in the stack it's not calling a method in OGNL. OGNL has a syntax for calling methods on objects `method()`.