# How to use JSTL <c:forEach> with Struts2 <s:url>?

Tags: jsp, struts2, iterator, jstl, ognl

I have this code that actually works:

```
<s:iterator value="breadcrumb.links" var="link">
    <s:url action='%{#link.url}' var="url" />
    <li>
       <a href="${url}">${link.name}</a>
    </li>
</s:iterator>
```

How con I do the same thing but with c:foreach instead of s:iterator ?

I tried with:

```
<c:forEach items="${breadcrumb.links}" var="link">
    <s:url action='${link.url}' var="url" />
    <li>
        <a href="${url}">${link.name}</a>
    </li>
</c:forEach>
```

but I get the error:

> According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute action does not accept any expressions

Thankyou.

Comment: Apart from the question, why do you want to do that ?

Comment: Becouse I don't feel confortable with struts tags s:iterator and OGNL %{#}. I'd like to stick to JSTL c:foreach and EL ${}. Also I always read that EL and OGNL can do the same things, only in different ways. But in this case I cant't find a way with EL.

Comment: This evening I'll try you code and post the results, thankyou.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be more comfortable with Struts2 tags and OGNL language, [read and bookmark this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11620838/1654265).

Since Struts2 tags only evaluate OGNL expressions ([and not EL Expression](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/why-cant-i-use-jstl-style-el-expressions-in-struts-tags.html), as you error clearly states), you need to access the JSTL object through the PageContext attribute (in OGNL `#attr.something`)  specified with `var` :

```
<c:forEach items="${breadcrumb.links}" var="link">
    <s:url action='%{#attr.link.url}' var="url" />
    <li>
        <a href="${url}">${link.name}</a>
    </li>
</c:forEach>
```

From [OGNL Basics](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/ognl-basics.html):

> `#attr['foo']` or `#attr.foo` 
>   : Access to `PageContext` if available, otherwise searches
>   `request`/`session`/`application` respectively

Comment: Thank you, it works as expected. I also read some docs about OGNL, now it is a lot clearer. Maybe I'll just switch to struts2 tags + OGNL. Grazie mille.

Comment: Glad that helped, prego :]