# Struts2 Tiles setting a var to a tiles attribute as string

Tags: jsp, struts2, tiles2

I use struts 2.3.16 and tiles 2.0.6.

A tiles definition with an empty attribute (among others):

```
<put-attribute name="pageSidePanel" value="" />
```

Some other definitions extend  it, and they can choose to either fill in the value:

```
<put-attribute name="pageSidePanel" value="/panels/greenPanel.jsp" />
```

or leave it empty as well.

I tried to test on whether or not this attribute is empty by using a struts "set" tag and some basic if/else logic. For example:

```
<s:set var="sidePanelName"><tiles:getAsString name='pageSidePanel'/></s:set>
<s:if test='%{#sidePanelName.isEmpty()}'>TRUE</s:if><s:else>FALSE</s:else>
```

The results were not what I expected. I performed 11 logical tests, in two variation: 11 tests used the hashtag, and the other 11 did not:

```
#sidePanelName vs sidePanelName
```

I did the tests with 2 different JSP pages, one that has actually put a value in tiles and one that didn't. So in total there 44 logical tests:

1. 11 tests using # on a page where the tiles attribute is empty
2. 11 tests not using # on a page where the tiles attribute is empty
3. 11 tests using # on a page where the tiles attribute is filled in with a value
4. 11 tests not using # on a page where the tiles attribute is filled in with a value

ONLY situation 3 was correct. All the other situation gave wrong results. For example, in situation 1, if I test `#var == null` I get false, but if I test `var == null` (without the hashtag) `i` get true. So there's two things I need to clear up:

1. What is the effect of using # or not?
2. what is the effect of the tiles attribute having a value or not, Does the struts var regard it as null or as the empty string or does it depend on whether I used # or not?

For reference, here are all the tests:

```
<s:set var="sidePanelName"><tiles:getAsString name='pageSidePanel'/></s:set>

<s:if test='#sidePanelName != ""'>TRUE</s:if><s:else>FALSE</s:else>
<s:if test="#sidePanelName != ''">TRUE</s:if><s:else>FALSE</s:else>
<s:if test='#sidePanelName == ""'>TRUE</s:if><s:else>FALSE</s:else>
<s:if test="#sidePanelName == ''">TRUE</s:if><s:else>FALSE</s:else>
<s:if test='%{!#sidePanelName.isEmpty()}'>TRUE</s:if><s:else>FALSE</s:else>
<s:if test='%{#sidePanelName.length() > 0}'>TRUE</s:if><s:else>FALSE</s:else>
<s:if test='%{#sidePanelName.length() == 0}'>TRUE</s:if><s:else>FALSE</s:else>
<s:if test='%{#sidePanelName.equals("")}'>TRUE</s:if><s:else>FALSE</s:else>
<s:if test='%{#sidePanelName.equalsIgnoreCase("")}'>TRUE</s:if><s:else>FALSE</s:else>
<s:if test='#sidePanelName == null'>TRUE</s:if><s:else>FALSE</s:else>
<s:if test='#sidePanelName != null'>TRUE</s:if><s:else>FALSE</s:else>

<s:if test='sidePanelName != ""'>TRUE</s:if><s:else>FALSE</s:else>
<s:if test="sidePanelName != ''">TRUE</s:if><s:else>FALSE</s:else>
<s:if test='sidePanelName == ""'>TRUE</s:if><s:else>FALSE</s:else>
<s:if test="sidePanelName == ''">TRUE</s:if><s:else>FALSE</s:else>
<s:if test='%{!sidePanelName.isEmpty()}'>TRUE</s:if><s:else>FALSE</s:else>
<s:if test='%{sidePanelName.length() > 0}'>TRUE</s:if><s:else>FALSE</s:else>
<s:if test='%{sidePanelName.length() == 0}'>TRUE</s:if><s:else>FALSE</s:else>
<s:if test='%{sidePanelName.equals("")}'>TRUE</s:if><s:else>FALSE</s:else>
<s:if test='%{sidePanelName.equalsIgnoreCase("")}'>TRUE</s:if><s:else>FALSE</s:else>
<s:if test='sidePanelName == null'>TRUE</s:if><s:else>FALSE</s:else>
<s:if test='sidePanelName != null'>TRUE</s:if><s:else>FALSE</s:else>
```

Comment: You should use `s:property` tag to output the value of `tiles:getAsString`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<tiles:getAsString>` tag will return empty string if you haven't defined its value in tiles definition. So your code

```
<s:set var="sidePanelName"><tiles:getAsString name='pageSidePanel'/></s:set>
```

will be the same as just an empty `<s:set>` tag.

```
<s:set var="sidePanelName"></s:set>
```

And an empty `<s:set>` tag w/o `value` attribute will assign the `top` to a variable (in most cases it would be the current action instance).

Try to print its value with `<s:property value="#sidePanelName"/>`. You will probably see something like `your_package.YourClass@hash`.

Comment: `<tiles:getAsString>` throws a `JSPException` if named value is not found.

Comment: I mean it will not return empty string in that case.

Comment: @RomanC: Yes, if there is no definition at all. But OP said that there is definition but with empty value.

Comment: @RomanC: There is `ignore` attribute that you can use to ignore exception.

Comment: A definition has a value if it has a name, the only difference is that value is returned. And OP seems doesn't use `ignore` attribute.

Comment: @RomanC: What? There is difference between there is no `put-attribute` and `put-attribute` with empty value.

Comment: @RomanC: OP doesn't use `ignore` because he/she has `<put-attribute name="pageSidePanel" value="" />`.

Comment: Then OP said that the value is overridden.

Comment: @RomanC: Yes it is *overridden* with a value. So what? The named value is still found.

Comment: Can the value of attribute be `null` probably not because `toString()` is used on the value. But it could be empty, I need to check a struts tag, coz it's not documented ;)

Comment: @RomanC: The empty `set` tag will be evaluated to `top` so essentially to the current action instance.

Comment: That's right the `set` tag is evaluated to `top`. But in my case it's not an action. Ok, +1 for nice answer.

Comment: It is extremely important that an empty set will evaluate to top. Why is not a huge "note" in all the documentation regarding the set tag?! Thanks for clearing it out for me

Answer (score 1):

You can't invoke methods on a `null` object...

Then

- `isEmpty()` and `length()` are uncallable, because invoked on the object itself, while
- for the comparisons with `equals()` and `equalsIgnoreCase()`, they're callable without generating NPE if invoked on the known object , like `"".equalsIgnoreCase(#sidePanelName)`.

BTW, if the object is null, also `"".equalsIgnoreCase(#sidePanelName)` will give false, because it is not equals to an empty String, it is just null...

---

P.S: pay attention to your description, that is misleading:

> I have a tiles attribute that is **NOT of type string**
>
> [...]
>
> The results are CORRECT whenever **the string is not empty/is filled in/has at least one character-**

Comment: I cleaned up the question and added more details/results. Could you please clarify your answer with this new information? Especially the question: is the struts variable null if the tiles attribute is empty?

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20467947/1654265) and especially the answer linked in it, to avoid 22 tests :)

Comment: Thank you, this was necessary literature for me!