# how to pass HashMap from Action class to jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I'm working on java web application and am using struts2 framework. I need to pass HashMap or LinkedList from Action class to jsp page to displaying all records.

I do not want to use `<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>` library to fetch all records from jsp page.

my code -

```
public class ViewStatusSHAction extends ActionSupport {

private LinkedList<SBean> humans = null;
private LinkedHashMap<String, String> hashMap =null;

public LinkedHashMap<String, String> getHashMap() {
    return hashMap;
}

public void setHashMap(LinkedHashMap<String, String> hashMap) {
    this.hashMap = hashMap;
}

public LinkedList<SBean> getHumans() {
    return humans;
}

public void setHumans(LinkedList<SBean> humans) {
    this.humans = humans;
}

public String execute() {
    this.setHumans(new ViewStatusSHModel().getHumanDetails());
    return Action.SUCCESS;
}
}
```

I want to use JSP syntax to display all recoreds fetched from action, but I don't know to **how to get all records without `<s:iterator></s:iterator>`
tags?.**

Comment: Which tag do you want to use instead of iterator tag or may be you don't want to use JSP tags?

Comment: You can use [JSTL's forEach, with JSP EL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20467947/1654265). But I suggest you to stick with the Struts tags, unless you already know JSTL (it seems you don't) or you jump from S2 to not-S2 projects, where struts tags are not available.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.