# Make ${} operator XSS safe in Struts 2 (same as tapestry)

Tags: jsp, struts2, jstl, xss, ognl

As mentioned in http://www.disasterarea.co.uk/blog/xss-vulnerabilities-in-web-frameworks-2/

> The ${} is not xss safe in struts 2 while it is safe in tapestry 5.

I am not a Tapestry guy, but I want to know if above is correct.

As far as I know the `${}` is part of JSLT and it does not depend on any web frameworks. So if above sentence is correct and the `${}` is XSS safe in tapestry, how can we make it safe in struts 2.

Updated:

To test it I run struts2-showcase app, opened `modelDriven\modelDrivenResult.jsp` and add below line:

```
Am I safe  ${name}
```

Now when you run the show case and enter `<script> alert('xxxx') </script>` as gangester name you can see the alert!

Comment: Where did you find that *The ${} is not xss safe in struts 2*?

Comment: I have tested it! Two pages and one model driven action. First page populates the action with model second page shows some model properties with ${}. It is strust 2.3.16.2 with struts 2 jquery plugin 3.7.0 on apache-tomcat-7.0.42. Should I configure something?!

Comment: Please see my update, you can test it in struts show case

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. **Struts2** `<s:property value="name" />` is automatically escaped by default;
2. **JSTL** `<c:out value="${name}" />` is automatically escaped by default;
3. **JSP EL** `${name}` is NOT escaped.

You can explicitly escape it with `${fn:escapeXml(name)}` , or set the escape to be performed by default creating a custom ELResolver as described in this great article:

- *[**ELResolver Escapes JSP EL Values To Prevent Cross-Site Scripting**](http://pukkaone.github.io/2011/01/03/jsp-cross-site-scripting-elresolver.html)*

Comment: This is what I was looking for, escaping ALL ${}. Do you think there is a reason which this feature is not implemented in Struts 2 same as tapestry?

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi For the reason I gave you: Struts 2 uses JSP. JSP EL doesn't escape values rendered via `${}`. **Tapestry does not use JSP.**

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: make it safe either on entry into the app, or on the way to the view layer.

Tapestry's `${}` is safe because it's not using JSP/JSP EL. Not escaping stuff is one of the things you lose by using JSP EL's `${}` over things like `<c:out>` and so on.

Comment: +1 for describing why `${}` is xss safe in tapestry! (Tapestry does not use JSP!)