# PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'X' not found on type X

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, jstl

I have `viewprofile` action that displays the user's details and transaction history.

**`History.java`:**

```
public class History {

    private String transactionId;
    private Date transactionDate;
    private String movieTitle;
    private BigDecimal schedulePrice;
    private String mallName;
    private int scheduleCinema;
    private Date scheduleDate;
    private Time scheduleTime;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**`ViewProfileAction.java`:**

```
public class ViewProfileAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware, RequestAware {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Map<String, Object> session;
    private Map<String, Object> request;

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {      
        if(!session.containsKey("currentUserId")) {
            return "index"; // return to index if not logged in
        }

        String currentUserId = (String) session.get("currentUserId");       

        UserManager um = new UserManager();
        String registeredUserEmail = um.getCurrentUserDetail("user_email", currentUserId);
        Date registeredDate = um.getRegisteredDate(currentUserId);
        int totalTransactions = um.getTotalTransactions(currentUserId);

        List<History> historyList = new DatabaseManipulator().getTransactionHistory(currentUserId);

        request.put("registeredUserEmail", registeredUserEmail);
        request.put("registeredDate", registeredDate);
        request.put("totalTransactions", totalTransactions);
        request.put("historyList", historyList);

        return SUCCESS;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    @Override
    public void setRequest(Map<String, Object> request) {
        this.request = request;     
    }   
}
```

**`user-profile.jsp`:**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<body>
    <table class="displaytbl">
    <tr>
        <td class="maintitle" colspan="7">TRANSACTION HISTORY</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <!-- column titles -->
    </tr>
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${historyList.isEmpty()}">
            <tr>
                <td class="norecord" colspan="7">NO RECORDED TRANSACTIONS</td>
            </tr>
        </c:when>

        <c:otherwise>
            <c:forEach var="history" items="historyList">
            <tr>
                <td>${history.transactionDate}</td>
                <td>${history.movieTitle}</td>
                <td>${history.schedulePrice}</td>
                <td>${history.mallName}</td>
                <td class="center">${history.scheduleCinema}</td>
                <td>${history.scheduleDate}</td>
                <td>${history.scheduleTime}</td>
            </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
    </table>
</body>
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```
<action name="viewprofile" class="com.mypackage.action.ViewProfileAction">
    <result>/user-profile.jsp</result>
    <result name="index" type="redirect">/index.jsp</result>
</action>
```

**StackTrace:**

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'transactionDate' not found on type java.lang.String
```

I am not sure why it is throwing `PropertyNotFoundException` when I do have the said property in `History`. How to resolve such issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems like issue with below line in Jsp page. `history` will just to point plain String `historyList` and not your collection object.

```
<c:forEach var="history" items="historyList">
```

The below line actually tries to get `transactionDate` from `history` object which is nothing but just `a String onject`

```
<td>${history.transactionDate}</td>
```

The above no where will access below, you might need to use  `<c:forEach var="history" items="${historyList}">`

```
request.put("historyList", historyList);
```

Comment: I have changed to `items="${historyList}"` and it works now. How silly of me. Upvoted and accepted as answer. Sorry for my noob mistake.

Comment: @ohtph it can happen sometimes.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are completely bypassing the framework mechanisms; instead of using the `request`, use private attributes **with getters** and setters:

```
public class ViewProfileAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Map<String, Object> session;

    private List<History> historyList;
    private String        registeredUserEmail;
    private Date          registeredDate;
    private int           totalTransactions;

    /* Generate GETTERS AND SETTERS for above fields here */

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {      
        if(!session.containsKey("currentUserId")) {
            return "index"; // return to index if not logged in
        }

        String currentUserId = (String) session.get("currentUserId");

        UserManager um = new UserManager();
        registeredUserEmail = um.getCurrentUserDetail("user_email", currentUserId);
        registeredDate = um.getRegisteredDate(currentUserId);
        totalTransactions = um.getTotalTransactions(currentUserId);

        historyList = new DatabaseManipulator().getTransactionHistory(currentUserId);

        return SUCCESS;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session) {
        this.session = session;
    }    
}
```

Also avoid using JSP EL [due to security issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23367430/1654265) and reduced capabilities, both to JSTL and to Struts2 Tags + OGNL, that would be the perfect choice in a Struts2 project.

And the user-in-session check can be performed once in an Interceptor, without the need to put it in *every* action of your project; read how to [write your own Interceptor for Session checking](http://andrealigios.blogspot.it/2012/08/struts2-write-your-own-interceptor-for.html).

Comment: Hi, does it mean if I change my `${}` to `<c:out value="${name}" />` it will ward off XSS attacks?

Comment: Exactly. Also if you change it to `<s:property value="%{name}"/>`.

Comment: Oh my god I have to change a LOT. Hahaha. Thank you very much Andrea, Honestly, I am unsure how exactly XSS is performed, but our web projects will be tested for "XSS" on defense/finals day. I will begin the changes now, thank you for the tip. (I have upvoted your answer btw.)

Comment: You should acquire the other suggestions in this answer too: you are using 10% of Struts2 framework right now... :| P.S: If you found that XSS answer useful, please consider upvoting it, thanks