# Struts2: Unable to fetch values from value stack

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, valuestack

```
<s:property value="%{sourceName}"/>  
<input type="text" name="sourceName" size="40" maxlength="25000" id="sourceName" class="gray" value="%{sourceName}"/>
```

`<s:property>` prints the string present in sourceName, but unable to set the value attribute for textfield to sourceName.

Why is it that I am able to access value from value stack at some places and not at others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `%{}` is an [OGNL notation](https://struts.apache.org/docs/ognl.html), and hence can be used in Struts tags only.

The other one, in a simple HTML tag, should be a JSP EL notation, `${}` (or printed with the whole `<s:property />` tag).

BTW Struts tags (and/or JSTL tags) are usually preferred to plain JSP EL because of different reasons, [including security](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23367430/1654265).

P.S: read [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11620838/1654265) to better understand the several notations involved.