# Struts 2 textfield accented char

Tags: html, jsp, struts2

I have this code in my jsp

```
<%-- debugging pourpose --%>
<s:property value="%{dettaglio.titolo}"/>

<%-- input field --%>
<div class="form-group" id="form-titolo">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label no-padding-right"
        for="titoloLivello">* Titolo </label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <s:textfield disabled="true"  id="titoloLivello" name="dettaglio.titolo"
            class="form-control col-xs-10 col-sm-12" value="%{dettaglio.titolo}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

[And that's the output I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pO6eV.png) :(

Anyone has an idea about why this happens?

On the top of the page I have this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="it">
        <head>

            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />

...
```

Answer (score 0):

[Struts2  is automatically escaped by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23365225/make-operator-xss-safe-in-struts-2-same-as-tapestry/23367430#23367430)

You have to take care of this escaping on your action class if you want to use on other tags that are not escaped automatically.