# How do I show elements of a Map's value (List of Objects) in a Struts 2 optgroup?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, optgroup

EDITED: I tried asking this in another question, since I felt that the originally asked question was sufficiently answered.  I got chastised for doing that.  So I've edited this question accordingly.  Basically, I don't know the right syntax to access the properties of the List of Employees that are in the "value" of each Map entry.

---

I have a TreeMap stored in session variable.  The "key" of the TreeMap holds a String.  The "value" of the holds a List of Objects.  The TreeMap is populated in the Action class.  A sample TreeMap might look like this:

```
ArrayList<Employee> employeeList1 = new ArrayList<Employee>();
Employee myEmployee = new Employee();
myEmployee.setEmployeeId("123");
myEmployee.setEmployeeName("John Doe");
employeeList1.add(myEmployee);

myEmployee = new Employee();
myEmployee.setEmployeeId("456");
myEmployee.setEmployeeName("Jane Doe");
employeeList1.add(myEmployee);
...

TreeMap<String,Employee> availableSupervisorsMap = new TreeMap<String,Employee>();
availableSupervisorsMap.put("A", employeeList1);
availableSupervisorsMap.put("B", employeeList2);
availableSupervisorsMap.put("C", employeeList3);
session.setAttribute("availableSupervisorsMap", availableSupervisorsMap);
```

In the JSP, I want to show a select box with each "key" as an optgroup label, and each employeeId and employeeName in the "value"'s list of Employee objects as the option value and display, respectively.  I tried the code below, to no avail:

```xml
<s:select name="availableIds" list="%{#session.availableSupervisorsMap}" multiple="true">
  <s:optgroup label="%{key}">
    <s:iterator value="%{value}">
        <option value="<s:property value="employeeId"/>">
            <s:property value="employeeName"/>
        </option>
     </s:iterator>
   </s:optgroup>
</s:select>
```

So the select box SHOULD look something like this, minus the bullet points of course:

- **A**

  - John Doe
  - Jane Doe
- **B**

  - 1st employeeName of employeeList2
  - 2nd employeeName of employeeList2
  - xth employeeName of employeeList2
- **C**

  - 1st employeeName of employeeList3
  - 2nd employeeName of employeeList3
  - xth employeeName of employeeList3

when I try the JSP code above, the following HTML is generated:

```
<select name="availableIds" id="AssignmentSupervisors_availableIds" multiple="multiple">

<option value="A">[Employee:
=========================================================
 employeeName =            John Doe
 employeeId =              123
=========================================================
, Employee:
=========================================================
 employeeName =            Jane Doe
 employeeId =              456
]</option>

<optgroup 
>
```

I have verified that the map is populated exactly as I expect it to be.  So it's making it to the JSP with the correct data.

Comment: I don't know what other users did, I've not downvoted your other question, just commented it, and the meaning was: if you've used a wrong syntax here, and from the answer you've got the right syntax, when you ask a second question, please use the right syntax from this answer, not the wrong syntax from this question.

Comment: @AndreaLigios I wanted to finish my testing first...and I did.  Thank you so much!  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You're confusing `%{}` with `#` and `#{}` ([three different things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11620838/1654265));
2. When you iterate a collection, the current object is pushed onto the value stack, so you don't need to mention the collection anymore. You can however get a reference to the current object by using the `var` keyword;
3. You're misusing the IteratorStatus.

The correct code is easier than you think:

```xml
<s:select name="availableIds" list="%{#session.availableSupervisorsMap}" multiple="true">
  <s:optgroup label="key">
    <s:iterator value="value" var="currentRow">
        <option value="%{#currentRow.employeeId}">
            <s:property value="%{#currentRow.employeeName}"/>
        </option>
     </s:iterator>
   </s:optgroup>
</s:select>
```